# ¿Cómo deserializar Json en C#? - Web API

Tags: c#, json, webapi

Tengo este json que me es retornado de un API y no logro guardar los datos, si me pueden decir si estoy haciendo mal el modelo o la conversión se lo agradecería

El json es el siguiente

```
{
 "respuesta": true,
 "sesion": true,
 "mensaje": "",
 "datos": {
    "1": {
      "fiproveedor_id": "1",
      "nombreProveedor": "Luz   Elvira",
      "fcestatus": "Activo",
      "fccorreo_electronico": "luz@hp.com",
      "fcnombre_empresa": "HP   center",
      "fcrazon_social_empresa": "XXXX"
    },
    "2": {
      "fiproveedor_id": "2",
      "nombreProveedor": "Victor daniel Marchan   trejo",
      "fcestatus": "Activo",
      "fccorreo_electronico": "victord90@hotmail.com",
      "fcnombre_empresa": "HP   center",
      "fcrazon_social_empresa": "XXXX"
    },
    "3": {
      "fiproveedor_id": "3",
      "nombreProveedor": "Victor daniel Marchan   trejo",
      "fcestatus": "Activo",
      "fccorreo_electronico": "victord90@hotmail.com",
      "fcnombre_empresa": "Telcel",
      "fcrazon_social_empresa": "JGFDSAF"
    }
  }
}
```

Trate de usar un modelo y guardarlo así

```
Respuesta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListadoModel>(content2);
```

El modelo que uso es el siguiente, es un modelo que tiene dentro una lista de otro modelo.

```
public class ListadoModel
    {
        public Boolean respuesta { set; get; }
        public Boolean sesion { set; get; }
        public string mensaje { set; get; }
        public List<ListaProveedoresModel> datos { set; get; }

    }

public class ListaProveedoresModel
{
    public int fiproveedor_id { set; get; }
    public String nombreProveedor { set; get; }
    public String fcestatus { set; get; }
    public String fccorreo_electronico { set; get; }
    public String fcnombre_empresa { set; get; }
    public String fcrazon_social_empresa { set; get; }

}
```

Estuve buscando y leí algo de un `JsonArray` o algo así pero no se si es lo que necesito.

Comment: Qué resultado obtenés con ese código? Logras obtener el objeto pero algunos datos no están o te arroja algún error??

Comment: Obtengo el siguiente error: 


Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[AplicacionMovil.Models.ListaProveedoresModel]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te das cuenta, el objeto `data:` de tu Json es un array o lista del tipo **Key/Value**, donde el **Key** es un `Int` y el **Value** es un objeto del tipo `ListaProveedoresModel`.

```
 // EL KEY
 "1": 
 // EL VALUE
 {
  "fiproveedor_id": "1",
  "nombreProveedor": "Luz   Elvira",
  "fcestatus": "Activo",
  "fccorreo_electronico": "luz@hp.com",
  "fcnombre_empresa": "HP   center",
  "fcrazon_social_empresa": "XXXX"
 }
```

Entonces, para deserializar, **no** vas a poder utilizar `List<>`. Debes utilizar una estructura que te permita asignar estos Key/Value, como por ejemplo un **`Dictionary<Key,Value>`**.

```
public class ListadoModel
{
    public Boolean respuesta { set; get; }
    public Boolean sesion { set; get; }
    public string mensaje { set; get; }
    public Dictionary<int, ListaProveedoresModel> datos { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Funciona gracias

Answer (score 1):

El problema inicial es que ***datos*** no es justamente una lista, para solucionar esto, podes crear una clase del tipo *Datos* y dentro va a tener los tres elementos, pero aquí vas a tener otro problema y es que las propiedades no pueden comenzar con un número, para esto vas a tener que utilizar [JsonPropertyAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) dónde indicas que una propiedad del Json se enlaza con otra de tu modelo.

Quedaría así:

```
public class ListadoModel
{
    public Boolean respuesta { set; get; }
    public Boolean sesion { set; get; }
    public string mensaje { set; get; }
    public Datos datos { set; get; }
}


public class Datos
{
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public ListaProveedoresModel One { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("2")]
    public ListaProveedoresModel Two { set; get; }

    [JsonProperty("3")]
    public ListaProveedoresModel Three { set; get; }
}

public class ListaProveedoresModel
{
    public int fiproveedor_id { set; get; }
    public String nombreProveedor { set; get; }
    public String fcestatus { set; get; }
    public String fccorreo_electronico { set; get; }
    public String fcnombre_empresa { set; get; }
    public String fcrazon_social_empresa { set; get; }

}
```

**Edito:** Si la cantidad de items es dinámica entonces podes utilizar un [Dictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8), nuevamente el tema está en que datos no es un [List](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8).

Quedaría así:

```
public class ListadoModel
{
    public Boolean respuesta { set; get; }
    public Boolean sesion { set; get; }
    public string mensaje { set; get; }
    public Dictionary<int, ListaProveedoresModel> datos { set; get; }
}
```

Comment: Pero datos no siempre son 3 , podrian ser 100, 67 o los que retorne la base, como seria para una cantidad dinamica?

Comment: perdón @rances5171 palmé anoche, ahí edité la solución para que te sirva con ítems dinámicos!

Comment: Funciona gracias, no sabia sobre los Dictionary

Comment: Genial, me alegra saber que sirvió!